# SignalR Stops Working for Certain Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

We have a SignalR application that is up and running, and has been very reliable to date.  A new user started access it and finds that updates stop being received about 1-2 minutes after the page loads (they do work for the first 1-2 minutes).  The browser is IE9, which works fine for other users.  The user is on the LAN (it's an internal application), so there are no connectivity issues.

What are some environmental issues that could cause this sort of behavior with SignalR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came down to IE9 being set to compatibility mode for intranet sites.  I'm not sure *why* it causes this specific problem, but changing that fixed it.